# How Do I know which Version of Beta OS X I'm Running?

Tags: macos, build-version

How do I know which Beta Version of OS X I'm running?

When I check About this Mac it shows me that the name of the OS version is OS X El Capitan, the version if 10.11 and a beta, and it shows me the build number, but how would I find out which specific beta release this is?

IE, how would I find out if build 15A235d as in the picture below corresponds with OS X El Capitan Developer Beta 4, 5, or 6?

Is there a way to find it out within the OS? Is there some kind of public database online like everymac.com where every build number is matched up with every name it was given?

[image: Image of the About this Mac window showing: OS X El Capitan; Version 10.11 Beta (15A235d)]

Comment: [OS X El Capitan Beta 5 Released for Developer Testing](http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/27/os-x-el-capitan-beta-5-released-for-developer-testing/)

Comment: The above comment link has your answer, although it is an incomplete reply. But the OS X Daily page just confirms that this is the fifth developer Beta, number as shown in your About This Mac: Beta 15A235d.

Comment: @Zo219: that page answers my specific question, but I'm looking for something more general to mark as the correct answer.

Comment: I was really hoping to grab the kernel from an RSS feed, but can't seem to find a reliable one.  `sw_vers` shows the macOS version and kernel, but no reference to the beta version that it's associated with.  Same goes for `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist `.  Happy to write a one-liner if someone can find a RSS, XML or JSON file online that has this info.  I'm even OK parsing HTML, but in my experience they use separate pages for each beta announcement.

Answer (score 1):

Login to developer.apple.com with your developer account, you should see in the download section the current release build on the download page for OS X.

- Go to **developer.apple.com** and login with your credentials
- Navigate to the **Member Center** section
- Select OS X
- On the download tab you will find the current build

This is to answer *how* to find the build as per OP.

Comment: I believe this is on topic, because I'm asking about finding the name of beta versions in general, not just developer betas. For example, El Capitan has had multiple public beta releases (at least two, maybe three?) so far. The link you gave suggests that public betas are fine to ask about.

Comment: This is outdated now